# How can I create an object dynamically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to create a list of objects to replace this method of creating them:

```
        var colors= new List<object>()
        {
            new {key="1",value="red"},
            new {key="2",value="white"},
            new {key="3",value="blue"}
        };
```

I want to create my object using keys and values from lists instead of hard coding.  Something like this:

```
    var colors= new List<object>()
        List<String> Keys= new List<String>();
        List<String> Values= new List<String>();

       for( int i = 0; i<Keys.count();++i)
   {
    colors.Add( put logic to add keys and values to colors object(s) here)  
   };
```

How can I accomplish this:  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var colors= new List<object>()
        List<String> Keys= new List<String>();
        List<String> Values= new List<String>();

   for( int i = 0; i<Keys.count();++i)
   {
     colors.Add( new {key=Keys[i],value=Values[i]})  
   }
```

Try the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a much more expressive way using Linq, in particular [`Enumerable.Zip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
List<string> keys = ...;
List<string> values = ...;

var colors = keys.Zip(values, (k, v) => new { key = k, value = v }).ToList();
```